# How to get start and end date of week by using week number and year and insert those dates into mysql table in c#

Tags: c#, mysql

What I'm trying to do is on selecting a week number of the year from the asp dropdown I want to insert the dates between start and end date of the week into the MySql table. But When I try it I'm not getting an error but instead the table gets filled with 01-01-0001 And it keeps on going without stopping and the connection doesn't close as it is on loop.

```
    private IEnumerable<Week> GetWeeksOfTheYear(int year)
    {
        var firstDayOfYear = new DateTime(year, 1, 1);
        var beginningDayOfWeek = firstDayOfYear.AddDays(-1 * Convert.ToInt32(firstDayOfYear.DayOfWeek));
        var endingDayOfWeek = beginningDayOfWeek.AddDays(6);
        var weekOfYear = 1;
        var weeksOfTheYear = new List<Week>();

        while (beginningDayOfWeek.Year < year + 1)
        {
            var week = new Week { Number = weekOfYear, BeginningOfWeek = beginningDayOfWeek };
            weeksOfTheYear.Add(week);

            beginningDayOfWeek = beginningDayOfWeek.AddDays(7);
            weekOfYear++;
        }

        return weeksOfTheYear;
    }


    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!this.IsPostBack)
        {
            ddlweek.DataSource = this.GetWeeksOfTheYear(DateTime.Now.Year);
            ddlweek.DataBind();
            ddlweek.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("--Select--", ""));
        }
    }
    private class Week
    {
        public DateTime BeginningOfWeek { get; set; }
        public DateTime EndOfWeek { get { return this.BeginningOfWeek.AddDays(6); } }
        public int Number { get; set; }
        public string Text { get { return this.ToString(); } }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return DateTime.Now > BeginningOfWeek && DateTime.Now < EndOfWeek
                ? String.Format(
                    "Week {0} or current week: {1} - {2}",
                    this.Number,
                    this.BeginningOfWeek.ToShortDateString(),
                    this.EndOfWeek.ToShortDateString())
                : String.Format(
                    "Week {0}: {1} - {2}",
                    this.Number,
                    this.BeginningOfWeek.ToShortDateString(),
                    this.EndOfWeek.ToShortDateString());
        }
    }
    DateTime BeginningOfWeek { get; set; }
    DateTime EndOfWeek { get; set; }
```

I get the dropdown list populated from the above.

```
    protected void Test_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        for(DateTime date = BeginningOfWeek; date <= EndOfWeek; date.AddDays(1))
        {
            MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection("Server=localhost;Database=mydb;Uid=myid;Pwd=abc123;");
            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("INSERT INTO shrinkageTool(date) VALUES(@date)");
            cmd.Connection = con;
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@date", date);
            con.Open();
            int result = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con.Close();

        }

    }
```

So how can I fix it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you stepped through the code in the debugger to observe what is happening?

Comment: @Crowcoder Like I said there is no error. Data gets inserted into table only not what I expected. It is not inserting the dates between BeginningOf Week and EndOfWeek instead is it inserting Date from 01-01-0001

Comment: I'm not talking about errors, I'm talking about stepping through your code and inspecting values as it runs. Your `while` condition doesn't behave as  you expect and you will probably see why it doesn't.

Comment: The thread 0x5494 has exited with code 0 (0x0). This is what I get and there are so many others like this

Answer (score 0):

1) To get weeks for particular year you have to use `Calendar.GetWeekOfYear` like

```
public List<int> GetWeeksInYear(int year)
{
    DateTimeFormatInfo dfi = DateTimeFormatInfo.CurrentInfo;
    DateTime date1 = new DateTime(year, 12, 31);
    System.Globalization.Calendar cal = dfi.Calendar;
    int weeks = cal.GetWeekOfYear(date1, dfi.CalendarWeekRule,
                                            dfi.FirstDayOfWeek);

    List<int> weekList = new List<int>();
    for (int i = 1; i <= weeks; i++)
    {
        weekList.Add(i);
    }

    return weekList;
}
```

2) To get the first day of week then pass year, your week number from above list and cultureinfo like

```
public static DateTime FirstDateOfWeek(int year, int weekOfYear, System.Globalization.CultureInfo ci)
{
    DateTime jan1 = new DateTime(year, 1, 1);
    int daysOffset = (int)ci.DateTimeFormat.FirstDayOfWeek - (int)jan1.DayOfWeek;
    DateTime firstWeekDay = jan1.AddDays(daysOffset);
    int firstWeek = ci.Calendar.GetWeekOfYear(jan1, ci.DateTimeFormat.CalendarWeekRule, ci.DateTimeFormat.FirstDayOfWeek);
    if ((firstWeek <= 1 || firstWeek >= 52) && daysOffset >= -3)
    {
        weekOfYear -= 1;
    }
    return firstWeekDay.AddDays(weekOfYear * 7);
}
```

3) To get last day of week then add 6 days to `firstDayOfWeek` like

```
public static DateTime LastDayOfWeek(DateTime firstDayOfWeek)
{
    return firstDayOfWeek.AddDays(6);
}
```

4) And use above dates like this

```
protected void Test_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    List<int> weekNumbers = GetWeeksInYear(2018);    

    DateTime firstDayOfWeek = FirstDateOfWeek(2018, weekNumbers.ElementAt(3), CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
    DateTime lastDayOfWeek = LastDayOfWeek(firstDayOfWeek);    

    for (var date = firstDayOfWeek; date.Date <= lastDayOfWeek; date = date.AddDays(1))
    {
        //Your rest of code is same here
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks but I'm getting an error when I try to pass the firstDayOfWeek and lastDayOfWeek into the for loop

Comment: did u successfully get `firstDayOfWeek` and `lastDayOfWeek` ? and please provide error

Comment: I fixed it but I can't pass the LastDay in the loop

Comment: operator <= cannot be operands of type DateTime and Method group

Comment: use like this in your for loop `DateTime firstDayOfWeek = FirstDateOfWeek(2017, 3, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
            DateTime lastDayOfWeek = LastDayOfWeek(firstDayOfWeek);`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/178325/discussion-between-prkash-and-ershoaib).

Comment: Thanks that really helped. I tried to get the firstDayOfWeek and lastDayOfWeek to show on the dropdown like I did on my code above but it's not working

Comment: Do you want to show firstDayOfWeek and lasDayOfWeek in dropdown?

Comment: Yep that's what I'm trying now. Lets see.